# Show/Hide div for a set period

Tags: jquery, html, forms

In my form, I hide the submit button upon click and show a div displaying `submitting...`.

It is very basic. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/44/).

The jQuery code is:

```
jQuery("#subnewtopicform").submit(function(e) {

    // Hide button by button ID
    jQuery("#subnewtopic").hide();

    // Show hidden div
    jQuery("#submitted").show();
});
```

And HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="subnewtopicform" />           
  Title:
 <input type="text" name="title" /><br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit Topic" class="button-primary" name="subnewtopic" id="subnewtopic" /> 
</form>

<div id="submitted" style="display:none">Submitting...</div>
```

My question is, how can I make it so that after 20 seconds, the `#subnewtopic` is shown again and `#subnewtopic` is hidden (back to how it was originally)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to achieve this
http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/47/

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("#subnewtopic").show();
    jQuery("#submitted").hide();
 },20000);
```

complete javascript could be:

```
jQuery("#subnewtopicform").submit(function(e) {

    // Hide button by button ID
    jQuery("#subnewtopic").hide();

    // Show hidden div
    jQuery("#submitted").show();

    setTimeout(function() {
       jQuery("#subnewtopic").show();
       jQuery("#submitted").hide();
    },20000);

});
```

Comment: That jsfiddle goes to the same as the one I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` to run a block of code after a set delay:

```
$("#subnewtopicform").submit(function (e) {
    $("#subnewtopic").hide();
    $("#submitted").show();

    setTimeout(function() {    
        $("#subnewtopic").show();
        $("#submitted").hide();
    }, 20000); 
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/46/)